# Spark 2.3.0 netty version issue: NoSuchMethod io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.metric()

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, netty

I just upgraded my spark project from 2.2.1 to 2.3.0 to find the versioning exception below. I have dependencies on the spark-cassandra-connector.2.0.7 and cassandra-driver-core.3.4.0 from datastax which in turn have dependencies on netty 4.x whereas spark 2.3.0 uses 3.9.x.

The class raising the exception, org.apache.spark.network.util.NettyMemoryMetrics, has been introduced in spark 2.3.0.

Is downgrading my Cassandra dependencies the only way round the exception? Thanks!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.metric()Lio/netty/buffer/PooledByteBufAllocatorMetric;
at org.apache.spark.network.util.NettyMemoryMetrics.registerMetrics(NettyMemoryMetrics.java:80)
at org.apache.spark.network.util.NettyMemoryMetrics.<init>(NettyMemoryMetrics.java:76)
at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.<init>(TransportClientFactory.java:109)
at org.apache.spark.network.TransportContext.createClientFactory(TransportContext.java:99)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.<init>(NettyRpcEnv.scala:71)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnvFactory.create(NettyRpcEnv.scala:461)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv$.create(RpcEnv.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:249)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:175)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:256)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:423)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems like you use an "too old" netty 4 version. Maybe you have multiple on your classpath ? It should be not problem to have netty 4.x and 3.x on the classpath.

Comment: Thanks you got on the right direction. I come from the .Net world and Scala is still a bit new to me. I eventually got it fixed following this: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: @rodders can you tell us, how did you fixed it?

Comment: I got by adding this fragment to my pom, and thus forcing a common netty reference:  
`  
    <dependencyManagement>  
        <dependencies>  
            <dependency>  
                <groupId>io.netty</groupId>  
                <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>  
                <version>4.1.17.Final</version>  
            </dependency>  
        </dependencies>  
    </dependencyManagement>  
`

Comment: @rodders I am also facing the same issue but in my case i am using pyspark(v 2.3.2) and hadoop (v2.8.3) . When i submit a pyspark job using spark-submit and open the logs of the yarn container i get the similar error. Due you have any idea how to solve it in case of pyspark

Comment: I had same problem and after excluding netty from  one of the dependency ` <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark-cassandra-connector_2.11.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>` it works for me

Answer (score 6):

I would like to add some more details to the answer for ease of work, just run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=io.netty:netty-all` it will return all the dependencies using `io.netty` and its version. In my case the culprit was Hive Jdbc 2.1.0 which has netty-all of version lower than the version used by spark 2.3.1 so the classpath omits to load the spark's netty as it was already loaded from hive-jdbc.

So the fix is to exclude the dependencies from the Hive-Jdbc in pom.xml

Comment: This option helped me out to figure out the problem. Thanks @Vicky

Comment: @JaiPrakash, I'm glad it helped you.!